# MongoDB - findOneAndUpdate with arrayFiters

Tags: mongodb

I'm having trouble using arrayFilters in MongoDB currently I have a document that looks like this

```
 {
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a5f814487c320156094c144"),
    "sender_id" : "123",
    "iso_number" : "ABC-DEF-123",
    "subject" : "Sample Memo",
    "content" : "This is a sample memorandum sent through postman.",
    "recipients" : [ 
        {
            "faculty_number" : 222,
            "_id" : ObjectId("5a5f814487c320156094c146"),
            "status" : "Sent"
        }, 
        {
            "faculty_number" : 111,
            "_id" : ObjectId("5a5f814487c320156094c145"),
            "status" : "Sent"
        }
    ],
    "memo_created" : ISODate("2018-01-17T17:00:52.104Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}
```

I want to update the status of the recipient with the faculty_number of 111 to "Seen". Based on the [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOneAndUpdate/), I can use `$[identifier] and arrayFilters` to specify which one I want to update.

I'm currently using this query:

```
db.getCollection('memos').findOneAndUpdate(
            {"_id": ObjectId("5a5f814487c320156094c144")},
            {$set: {"recipients.$[elem].status": "Seen"}},
            {arrayFilters: [{"elem.faculty_number": 111}]}
        )
```

But I get this error

```
Failed to execute script. Error: findAndModifyFailed failed: {
"ok" : 0,
"errmsg" : "cannot use the part (recipients of recipients.$[elem].status) to traverse the element ({recipients: [ { faculty_number: 456, _id: ObjectId('5a5f7c849c70ee3c3c7c28f3'), status: \"Sent\" }, { faculty_number: 789, _id: ObjectId('5a5f7c849c70ee3c3c7c28f2'), status: \"Sent\" } ]})",
"code" : 16837,
"codeName" : "Location16837" } : _getErrorWithCode@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:25:13 DBCollection.prototype.findAndModify@src/mongo/shell/collection.js:768:1 DBCollection.prototype.findOneAndUpdate@src/mongo/shell/crud_api.js:823:12 @(shell):1:1
```

I just followed the example that was presented in the [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOneAndUpdate/).

Comment: What version of mongodb do you use? _arrayFilters_ has been added since 3.6. I get the same error on 3.4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the index of `"faculty_number" : 111,`
then update the sub-document using positional

```
db.memos.update(
    {
        "_id": ObjectId("5a5f814487c320156094c144"),
        "recipients.faculty_number": 111
    },
    {
        $set: {
            "recipients.$.status": "Sent"
        }
    }
)
```

ps: cant try findOneAndUpdate - not a function in my cli

Comment: It returns null after executing